# Scheme procedure in a list

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

So imagine i have a list '(+ (* (x) (5)) (2))
How would i make a procedure that changes the x to whichever parameter i give and then evaluates
the function inside the list?
((calculate expression x))

I had some ideas but didn't get it to work.
These are the helprocedures i made:

```
(define (atom? x)
  (not (pair? x)))

(define (deep-map f l)
  (cond
    ((null? l) '())
    ((atom? l) (f l))
    (else
     (cons (deep-map f (car l))
           (deep-map f (cdr l))))))


(define (deep-change e1 e2 l)
  (deep-map (lambda (x) (if (eq? x e1) e2 x)) l))

(define (go-through-list list)
  (if (null? list)
      '()
      ((car list) (go-through-list (cdr list)))))
```

Here is the main code:

```
    (define (calculate expression x)
  (let ((expressie (deep-change 'x x expression)))
    (('+ (deep-change '+ (+) expression)))
    (('- (deep-change '- (-) expression)))
    (('* (deep-change '* (*) expression)))
    (('/ (deep-change '/ (/) expression)))
    (go-through-list expression)))
```

I managed to change the x in to to parameter i give but have problems with the * and + inside the list.

Comment: what is the call you're making? what are the results? (unexpected answer, error -- if so, what is the error message? -- etc.) please include everything relevant.

Comment: `(let ((expressie ;....` -- is this a typo? As far as I can tell `expressie` is never used again.

Comment: `(+)`  is not the procedure `+`, it is 0. If `x` is a procedure, `(x)` calls the procedure without any arguments.

Comment: The `calculate` procedure makes no sense at all. What do you think an expression like `(('+ (deep-change '+ (+) expression)))` does?

Comment: `(+)` is applying `+` with no arguments. It is not the same as the variable  `+` that evaluates to the procedure you are applying in your logic. Same for `-` and `(/)` and `(*)` but they have `1` as default accumulator instead of 0.

Comment: Question title is "**Scheme procedure** in a **list**", but the list `'(+ (* (x) (5)) (2))` does not
represent a Scheme _expression_ (nor a procedure or function). @E.T. it's good that you had some ideas
and wrote some code, but can you edit the question to clarify the sorts of values allowed for
`expression` and `x` in `(calculate expression x)` ?
(or respond to questions in comments?)

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (replace x y tree)
  (cond ((null? tree) tree)
         ((not (or (pair? tree) (list? tree))) (if (eq? x tree) y tree))
         (else (cons (replace x y (car tree))
                     (replace x y (cdr tree))))))
```

And then you can simply `(replace 'x 42 expr)`.

Assuming the tree is then valid scheme code. You can simply `eval` it.

If you're trying to replace multiple variables, it might be wise write a replace-multiple function that will handle arbitrary number of variables so that you can do something like this

```
(replace-multiple '(x y z) '(1 2 3) expr)
```

Implementing this function is basically calling replace multiple times.
e.g.

```
(replace 'x 1 (replace 'y 2 (replace 'z 3 expr)))
```

So you might want to use recursion there.

If your scheme has the fold operator (provided by srfi-1), use it because it essentially achieves the above.

It would probably look something like this:

```
(define (replace-multiple xs ys tree)
  (fold replace tree xs ys))
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be an interesting question; consider this clarification:

**Evaluate list representing expression with free variable without using eval**

> What is a way to develop a function to evaluate a Scheme expression built from
> the four arithmetic operations, numbers, and a free variable x, without using `eval`?
> The function is given a list representing the expression and a value for x.
> Example: `(calculate  '(+ (* x 5) 2)  3)` => 17

Development is presented as a sequence of elaborations of the calculate function;
each `define` has a *Signature comment* on the same line, informally describing
argument/result types; function and following example(s) can be copy-pasted into a REPL.
Note: not all errors are detected; there is a compact version without comments at the end.

Getting started: write a function which works for the given example:

```
(define (calculate-0 expression-in-x value-for-x)  ;; '(+ (* x 5) 2) Number -> Number
  (if (equal? expression-in-x '(+ (* x 5) 2))
    (+ (* value-for-x 5) 2)
    (error #f "wrong expression" expression-in-x)))

(calculate-0 '(+ (* x 5) 2) 3) ;=> 17
```

Real function will have to extract pieces of `expression`
a simple example with all elements is `'(+ x 1)`:

```
(define (calculate-1 expression value)  ;; '(+ x <n>) Number -> Number
  (let ([procedure  (car expression)]
        [argument-1 (cadr expression)]
        [argument-2 (caddr expression)])
    (if (and (eq? procedure '+)
             (eq? argument-1 'x)
             (number? argument-2))
      (+ value argument-2)
      (error #f "expression" expression))))

(calculate-1 '(+ x 1) 2) ;=> 3
```

`+` in Scheme accepts any number of arguments, so replace `if` with map/cond:

```
(define (calculate-2 expression value)  ;; '(+ x|<n> ...) Number -> Number
  (let ([arguments (cdr expression)])
    (let ([arguments
            (map (lambda (argument)
                (cond         ;; (compare with (if ...) in calculate-1)
                  [(eq? argument 'x)  value ]
                  [(number? argument) argument ]
                  [else (error #f "argument" argument)]))
              arguments)])
      (apply + arguments))))

(calculate-2 '(+ 1 x) 2)    ;=> 3
(calculate-2 '(+ x 1 x) 3)  ;=> 7
(calculate-2 '(+) 99)       ;=> 0
```

Get all four operations working:

```
(define (calculate-3 expression value)  ;; '(op x|<n> ...) Number -> Number
  (let ([procedure (car expression)]
        [arguments (cdr expression)])
    (let ([arguments          ;; (same as calculate-2)
            (map (lambda (argument)
                (cond
                  [(eq? argument 'x)  value ]
                  [(number? argument) argument ]
                  [else (error #f "argument" argument)]))
              arguments)])
      (apply (case procedure
              [(+)  + ]
              [(-)  - ]
              [(*)  * ]
              [(/)  / ]
              [else (error #f "procedure" procedure)])
        arguments))))
        
(calculate-3 '(* x 5) 3)  ;=> 15
```

Allowing nested sub-forms needs just one small change:

```
(define (calculate-4 expression value)  ;; '(op x|<n>|Expr ...) Number -> Number
  (let ([procedure (car expression)]
        [arguments (cdr expression)])
    (let ([arguments
            (map (lambda (argument)
                (cond
                  [(eq? argument 'x)  value ]
                  [(number? argument) argument ]
                  [(pair? argument)                 ;; (<- only change)
                     (calculate-4 argument value) ] ;;
                  [else (error #f "argument" argument)]))
              arguments)])
      (apply (case procedure
              [(+)  + ]
              [(-)  - ]
              [(*)  * ]
              [(/)  / ]
              [else (error #f "procedure" procedure)])
        arguments))))
        
(calculate-4 '(+ (* x 5) 2) 3) ;=> 17
```

So there it is: try calculate-4 with the original example in the REPL:

```
$ scheme

> (calculate-4 '(+ (* x 5) 2) 3)
17
> ; works with all Scheme Numbers:
  (calculate-4 '(+ (* x 15/3) 2+2i) 3.0)
17.0+2.0i
>
```

Not so fast ... `expression` is a list with the form of a Scheme expression using four
operations, Numbers, and x. But the question doesn't require `value` to be a Number: *procedures are
first-class values in Scheme*
(expression could be `'(+ (x 3) 2)` with value `(lambda (n) (* n 5))` ):

```
(define (calculate-5 expression value)  ;; '(x|op x|<n>|Expr ...) Number|Lambda -> Value
  (let ([procedure (car expression)]
        [arguments (cdr expression)])
    (let ([arguments
            (map (lambda (argument)
                (cond
                  [(eq? argument 'x)  value ]
                  [(number? argument) argument ]
                  [(pair? argument)   (calculate-5 argument value) ]
                  [else (error #f "argument" argument)]))
              arguments)])
      (let ([procedure
              (cond           ;; (compare with argument cond above)
                [(eq? procedure 'x) value ]
                [(pair? procedure)  (calculate-5 procedure value)]
                [else (case procedure
                        [(+)  + ]
                        [(-)  - ]
                        [(*)  * ]
                        [(/)  / ]
                        [else (error #f "procedure" procedure)]) ]) ])
        (apply procedure arguments)))))
        
(calculate-5 '(+ (x 3) 2) (lambda (n) (* n 5))) ;=> 17
```

(And so, *finally*, our `calculate` function is "Hello World!" capable :)

```
$ scheme

> ;(copy-paste calculate-5 here)

> (calculate-5 '(x) (lambda _ 'Hello!))
Hello!
>
```

Compact version (returns #f on error):

```
(define (calculate expr value)
  (call/cc (lambda (error)
  (let* ([proc (car expr)]
     [args (map (lambda (arg) (cond
              [(eq? arg 'x) value]
              [(number? arg) arg]
              [(pair? arg)
                (or (calculate arg value) (error #f))]
              [else (error #f)]))
            (cdr expr))]
     [proc (cond
            [(eq? proc 'x) value ]
            [(pair? proc) (calculate proc value)]
            [else (case proc [(+) +] [(-) -] [(*) *] [(/) /]
                    [else (error #f)])])])
    (apply proc args)))))
```

Comment: The OP list `'(+ (* (x) (5)) (2))` does not represent a Scheme _expression_ (or 'procedure'), and can't be `eval`ed. `calculate` could be modified to ignore extra parentheses (but `(x)` would be a special case).